# Apache 2.4.53 Getting AH00027: No authentication done but request not allowed without authentication for /CN=XXXX. Authentication not configured?

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

We have an Apache 2.4.53 and when they try to access it we are seeing a 500 error, and the following in the error_log file:

```
[Thu Jan 25 23:56:22.600893 2024] [core:error] [pid 24313:tid 140492557752064] [client 172.31.xx.yy:39564] AH00027: No authentication done but request not allowed without authentication for /CN=XXXX.... Authentication not configured?
```

The ssl.conf has a VirtualHost set up:

```
<VirtualHost *:7513>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCompression off
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
  SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!NULL:!3DES
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
.
.
  SSLVerifyClient require
  SSLVerifyDepth  10
  SSLOptions +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars +LegacyDNStringFormat
  DocumentRoot "/apps/aaa/bbb"
  ServerName sim.foo.com
  ServerAlias sim.foo.com
  ScriptAlias /rest/users "/apps/aaa/bbb/test7.pl"
  <Directory "/apps/aaa/bbb">
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <Location /rest>
    AuthType None
    Require all granted
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't understand why we are getting this error, since the  and <Location /rest> seem like they should allow access, but I am also not that familiar with this particular system, so I was hoping that someone might be able to point me to what might be wrong and how to fix the problem?

Thanks,
Jim

EDIT1: Adding apachectl -S and apachectl -t outputs:

```
[root@simfed01 conf]# /apps/products/apache/2.4.53/bin/apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/apps/products/apache/2.4.53"
Main DocumentRoot: "/apps/products/apache/2.4.53/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "/apps/products/apache/2.4.53/logs/error_log"
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/apps/products/apache/2.4.53/logs/"     mechanism=default
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
PidFile: "/apps/products/apache/2.4.53/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="orcladmin" id=2008
Group: name="orcladmin" id=4503

[root@simfed01 conf]# /apps/products/apache/2.4.53/bin/apachectl -t
Syntax OK
```

Comment: I don't see the ssl_certificate specified `SSLCertificateFile      /path/to/signed_cert_and_intermediate_certs_and_dhparams
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /path/to/private_key `. Also do apachectl -S to show the running apache config and apachectl configtest to verify the config. But it looks you require client certificate authentication, so does the client have a client cert?

Comment: Turdie - I left those directives out so that post wasn't so long.  And yes, the client is sending a client cert.  BTW it seems like I need to change the directives inside the <Directory> and the <Location /rest> but it also seems like what is there should be sufficient.  That is what I am really unclear about.

Comment: Additional logs are required, including error and access logs. Please provide more details. Also, it appears that the full configuration has not been posted.

Comment: Can you please check if the ssl module is enabled `sudo a2enmod ssl` and then restart apache

Comment: Turdie, djdomi et al - This particular apache instance is one of several apache instances on this machine that are there in support of an Oracle product, so I have to be really careful with what I do lest I break something inadverdently.  I hope that you all understand.  I can assure you that this instance (and this specific VirtualHost) are enabled and working for client-authentication.  I also ran openssl s_client and verified that the server and CA certs are correct and also that the "acceptable" list of CAs was sent as part of the 2-way SSL.

Comment: I would stick with 'Require all granted' and stop mixing it with Allow directives anywhere. Having said that your apachectl -S does not even mention your virtualhost on port 7513, so it is not using it, make sure it is correctly included.